# Query to get current year from Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Trying to find the SQL query to get current year from Amazon redshift db.

Tried following queries but didn't worked :

```
select DATE_PART_YEAR(SYSDATE);
select DATE_PART_YEAR(getdate());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further reading through Amazon docs and with trial and error,
found following queries to work returning current year value :

```
select DATE_PART_YEAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE));
select DATE_PART_YEAR(TRUNC(getdate()));
select extract(year from sysdate);
select extract(year from current_date);
```

Trunc method removes the timezone part and returns date value, which is the value being expected by DATE_PART_YEAR method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
extract(year from current_date)
```

You might as well use standard SQL for this.  The above is standard.  There are numerous other alternatives, such as:

```
extract(year from sysdate)
date_part_year(trunc(getdate()))
to_char(current_date, 'YYYY')
```